# Cygwin doesn't recognize make command despite it being installed and in the bin folder

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I've been trying to run software on my W10 PC that requires `make`, this lead me to installing Cygwin. When looking Cygwin up I saw that I needed to install `make` from the Devel category, which I did the first time I installed Cygwin. I receieved the following message my first time trying to execute `make`:

> bash: make: command not found

I tried reinstalling `make` (the drop down literally said "Reinstall") and checking if `make.exe` was in the `bin` folder but I still got the same error. I reinstalled it a second time but checked the src box this time hoping that would help, but it didn't.

The only other piece of information I can think to add is that the Makefile that I'm trying to make is in a folder in my Documents folder in my C drive (`C:\Users\myname\Documents\folder\folder_with_Makefile`). I checked the Cygwin FAQ and it mentions that the Cygwin root directory isn't the same as my drives root directory by design, and to only change it if "you know what you are doing", which I clearly don't. I'm not sure if that might be the cause of my issue but I'd appreciate any help.

---

Output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/.cargo/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.2/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3/bin
```

This is where cygwin is installed: `C:\cygwin64`

Comment: How are you running bash ? What is the output of `echo $PATH` and of `cygcheck -c make` ?

Comment: I'm running bash through the Cygwin terminal in the directory with the file I want to make.
`echo $PATH` returns a file path that's too long to paste in this reply (I tried).
`cygcheck -c make` returns: `bash: cygcheck: command not found`

Comment: put the additional info in the question, not in the comment. You can edit your question. The `cygcheck: command not found` tell me that your shell is NOT properly setting the PATH or that in your PATH the executable are not allowed. In which folder have you installed Cygwin ?

Comment: @matzeri I've updated my original post with the output of `echo PATH` and the directory where Cygwin is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below changes which will help you to set the PATH variable correctly with cygwin.
You can perform the following changes. 
 
Open the file profile.bashrc present in etc/ directly where cygwin is installed.
Add below lines.

```
# Save Windows path variable
export WINPATH=$PATH
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Open bash.bashrc file present in etc/ directly where cygwin is installed.
Add below lines

```
# The next block is only needed in case somebody starts a shell without --login parameter in the beginning (no /etc/profile invoked)
# The WINPATH variable is set in /etc/profile and contains the original Win PATH variable content
if [ -z "${WINPATH}" ] ; then
   export WINPATH=$PATH
fi
# Set PATH variables
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:${WINPATH}
export MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man
```

Comment: I have no idea what you made me do but it seems to have worked. Thank you very much. Unfortunately I apparently don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are NOT running a login shell.

Simulating the effect with two batch files in the root directory, derived from the `Cygwin.bat` that is expected to be there

Case 1: Cygwin-nologin.bat
`Mintty` does not run `bash` as `login shell` and the `PATH` does not include `/usr/bin/`
where Cygwin commands are mainly located:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set TERM=
cd /d "%~dp0bin" && .\mintty
```

I run it and the effect is:

```
echo $PATH
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Calibre2:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/FreeFem++:/cygdrive/c/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps

$ which make
bash: which: command not found

$ /usr/bin/which make
/usr/bin/which: no make in (/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client: ...)
```

Case 2 : Cygwin-login.bat
`Mintty` does run `bash` as `login shell` and the `PATH` includes `/usr/bin/`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set TERM=
cd /d "%~dp0bin" && .\mintty -
```

The difference is in the last `-` character. `man mintty` for details

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

the PATH is very short as in my enviroment I set a specific variable

```
$ set |grep NOWIN
CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=YES
```

Otherwise the PATH will be the combination of the Cygwin and Windows PATH,
with the Cygwin one in front

```
$ echo ${PATH}":"${ORIGINAL_PATH}
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Calibre2:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/FreeFem++:/cygdrive/c/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
```

in both case

```
$ which make
/usr/bin/make

$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin
...
```